# Nested elasticsearch query for java QueryBuilders

Tags: java, elasticsearch, query-builder

I am trying to achieve this elasticsearch query in java querybuilder for elasticsearch. But i am not able to get the equivalent results. Can anyone help with this.

```
 GET /XX/XX/_search
    {
       "query": {
          "bool": {
             "must": [
                {
                   "nested": {
                      "path": "XX",
                      "filter": {
                         "term": {
                            "A": "7:140453136:T"
                         }
                      }
                   }
                },
                {
                   "nested": {
                      "path": "XX",
                      "filter": {
                         "term": {
                            "B": "RF"
                         }
                      }
                   }
                },
                {
                   "nested": {
                      "path": "XX",
                      "filter": {
                         "term": {
                            "C": "RFFF"
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
             ]
          }
       }
    }
```

The code which i tried:

```
   QueryBuilders qbWithArguments = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("A", "RF"))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("B", "EF"))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("C", "RF"));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add `nested query` too. Use below code:

```
QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(nestedQuery("XX", FilterBuilders.termFilter("A","RF")))
                             .must(nestedQuery("XX", FilterBuilders.termFilter("B","EF")))
                             .must(nestedQuery("XX", FilterBuilders.termFilter("C","RF")))
```

For higher versions you can use :

```
QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(nestedQuery("XX", QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
           .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("A","RF"))
           .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("B","EF"))
           .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("C","RF"))
           .minimumShouldMatch("1")))
```

Notes: In 6.7, even if the doc stayed that `ScoreMode` is optional, you may need to provide this param when using the java QueryBuilders.

Comment: nestedQuery() doesnt accept FilterBuilders as second argument. It expects QueryBuilder.

Comment: There is  an overloaded method in QueryBuilders class which accepts filterbuilder as second argument.    public static NestedQueryBuilder nestedQuery(String path, FilterBuilder filter) {
        return new NestedQueryBuilder(path, filter);
    }. Refer to http://rajish.github.io/api/elasticsearch/0.20.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT/org/elasticsearch/index/query/QueryBuilders.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference. But i am using ES 2.1.1 which is the latest and i dont see that overloaded method in the latest API doc.

Comment: FYI: org.elasticsearch.index.queries.FilterBuilders has been removed as part of the merge of queries and filters. These filters are now available in QueryBuilders with the same name. All methods that used to accept a FilterBuilder now accept a QueryBuilder instead.

Comment: Can you use QueryBuilders then? I have edited my answer according to that.

Comment: Thanks for the query! It works only if i provide all the three fields for search. But in my use case i want to see results even if i provide only one/two/three inputs. I mean to say if i provide one term for search the rest two will empty. but still i want to see results for the provided field. Should i replace must with should for this and add minimumShouldMatch to 1?

Comment: Yup that works as expected. Thanks a Ton. I am a new bee to ES :-) . Can you please mark this as the answer.